# Alternatives to Apply/Map in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, apply

I'm developing an ETL process and I would like to know if there is any alternative to improve the performance of my data-transforming.

I am applying this function to get the age and return the belonging age group of the given age.

```py
def ageGroup(x):
        if x>60:
              return ">60"
        elif x>50:
              return "From 51 to 60"
        elif x>40:
              return "From 41 a 50"
        elif x>30:
              return "From 31 a 40"
        elif x>20:
              return "From 21 a 30"
        else:
              return "<21"
```

At the beginning I started to use apply.

```py
Cst["age_group"]= Cst["age"].apply(lambda x: ageGroup(x))
```

And this give and avg time of # --- 0.0012826919555664062 seconds ---.

Then I read that map it's slightly faster in this cases and I try it.

```py
Cst["age_group"]= Cst["age"].map(ageGroup)
```

But only improve a little the time of execution. (# --- 0.001134634017944336 seconds MAP ---
)

So after research, I find this other approach using np that honestly not worked as I expected.

```py
#     Cst["age_group"] = np.select(
 #         [
 #             Cst["age"].between(-1, 20, inclusive=True), 
 #             Cst["age"].between(21, 30, inclusive=True),
 #             Cst["age"].between(31, 40, inclusive=True),
 #             Cst["age"].between(41, 50, inclusive=True),
 #             Cst["age"].between(51, 60, inclusive=True),
 #         ], 
 #         [
 #         "<21", 
 #         "From 21 to 30",
 #         "From 31 to 40",
 #         "From 41 to 50",
 #         "From 51 to 60",
         
         
 #         ], 
 #         default=">60"
 #     )
```

So Im here just to ask you if you know another approach to make my work more efficiently.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) your data with various bins, supplying the appropriate labels.

```
pd.cut(
    cst['age'], bins=[0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, np.inf], right=True, include_lowest=True,
    labels=["<21", "From 21 to 30", "From 31 to 40", "From 41 to 50", "From 51 to 60", '60+'])
```

Note that this returns a categorical series. If you want strings, append `.astype(str)`.

Comment: Since he was interested in performance, I'll note that
`timeit(lambda : df.age.map(ageGroup), number =100)` returns 1.5 seconds
`timeit(lambda : pd.cut(df.age, [0,16,21,35,60,np.inf]) , number =100)` returns 0.34 seconds

Comment: `numpy_select` could be helpful here as well, although `pd.cut` is a good and efficient  abstraction